# How to copy complete folder structure to another folder in AWS s3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have below folder structure in S3 bucket
**Source:**

2022-09-09/EOD/9898/**STAGED**/1/abc.txt

2022-09-09/EOD/9898/**STAGED**/1/test.csv

2022-09-09/EOD/9898/**STAGED**/2/abc1.txt

2022-09-09/EOD/9898/**STAGED**/2/test1.csv

**Destination:**

2022-09-09/EOD/9898/**PROCESSED**/1/abc.txt

2022-09-09/EOD/9898/**PROCESSED**/1/test.csv

2022-09-09/EOD/9898/**PROCESSED**/2/abc1.txt

2022-09-09/EOD/9898/**PROCESSED**/2/test1.csv

The contents under **STAGED** directory should be copied to **PROCESSED** directory with exact child directories .

Tried below code .But no luck:

```
String dest=("2022-09-09/EOD/9898/).concat("PROCESSED").concat("/");
String source=("2022-09-09/EOD/9898/).concat("STAGED").concat("/");

ListObjectRequest lst=new ListObjectRequest().withBucketName("myBucket").withPrefix(source).withDelimiter("/");
ObjectListing list=amazonS3.listObjects(lst)
list.getObjectSummaries()./stream().forEach(s3Summary->{

CopyObjectRequest cor=new CopyObjectRequest ("myBucket",s3Summary.getKey(),"s3Summary",dest);
amazonS3.copyObject(cor);
});
```

Did not work..Can some one please help

Comment: What is the error massage

Comment: @ZabielskiGabriel  ..No ERROR ..But nothing got copied also

Comment: You're copying all the objects to the same key, instead of `dest`, you probably want to create unique keys per object with something like `s3Summary.replace(source, dest)`

Comment: The code is currently copying every object to a destination Key of `2022-09-09/EOD/9898/PROCESSED/`. Unlike operating systems, Amazon S3 does not interpret this as "please copy the object to _inside_ this folder". Rather, it is treating that string as the actual Key (including the final slash). There, all objects are being copied to the same destination Key. You will need to append the 'filename' to the end of the Key, as suggested by @AnonCoward.